# How did Christmas get electricity?

Tags: doctor-who

In *The Time of The Doctor*, we saw light bulbs in Christmas. Christmas didn't look like to have a nuclear power plant. Solar Energy was out of question because Sunshine was visible only for few minutes each day (getting a Solar Cell should be main problem, however).

How does Christmas get electricity? Are there other slightly advanced civil areas on Trenzalore?

Comment: There are many, many more ways to generate electricity than just nuclear and solar power.

Comment: @BrianS They are just examples to assert that Christmas wasn't industrially advanced.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The technology may have been somewhat more advanced than it appeared, since apparently it was a colony world, so it must have been settled by people capable of long-range space travel. From the [transcript](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/33-16.html):

> DOCTOR: Right. What's the signal? Where's it coming from?
>
> TASHA: It's a settlement. Human colony, level two. A farm, basically.

While I don't think anything in the episode itself suggested anything about the type of power generation used, some of the spin-off short stories mentioned in the the [Trenzalore TARDIS wiki article](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Trenzalore), both from the book [*Tales of Trenzalore*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1849908443), say that the original colonists had tapped underground hot springs, so that may suggest the colonies run on geothermal power:

> Approximately 150 years before the Eleventh Doctor began his residency
>   on Trenzalore, humans colonists settled on the planet. Some of the
>   first colonists were Jalen Fellwood and Roland Treece, both of whom
>   became headsmen at a time when the Truth Field did not yet exist.
>   (PROSE: The Dreaming) The early settlements stockpiled boronite, which
>   they used to reach underground hot springs by exploding the bedrock
>   that covered them. The leftover boronite was eventually shelved.
>   (PROSE: Strangers in the Outland)